# Line 10: Char 31: runtime error: store to address 0x7fff6774f4f4 with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'

Tags: c

I'm getting this run time error I don't know what's wrong with the code.
"**Line 10: Char 31: runtime error: store to address 0x7fff6774f4f4 with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'** "

```
int *twoSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int target, int *returnSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++)
        {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
            {
                returnSize[0] = i;
                returnSize[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnSize;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: you could `break` out of the loops (or return directly) after finding a match, rather than continue searching through all the remaining pairs.

Comment: Can you show us how you call your function? For example, what is given as the fourth argument? If "Line 10" is `returnSize[1] = j;`, then maybe you're giving it the address of a *single* `int` rather than an array of (at least) two `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is the Twosum problem in leetcode. If it is, then the fourth argument `*returnSize` is not an array but a pointer to an integer which is the size of the array you should return. Here's the code with modification.

```
int *twoSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int target, int *returnSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++)
        {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
            {
                *returnSize = 2;
                int *rtn = (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
                rtn[0] = i;
                rtn[1] = j;
                return rtn;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: so `returnSize`is not really used?

Comment: @Ivan yes. It may be used by the main function but the main function is not visible in leetcode.

Comment: @susanth29 thanks for the help. I was stuck on this for the last 3 days (trying to figure it out on my own).

Comment: Maybe they want several results??? `twoSum((int [5]){2, 8, 5, 3, 7}, 5, 10, &n)` would return a malloc'd array with `{0, 1, 3, 4}` and set `n = 2 /* 2 pairs found */`?

Comment: @pmg Assuming the question is from leetcode, It is mentioned in the question that each input has exactly one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since returnSize is not an array but a pointer point to an integer which tells how many numbers will be returned in the returned array. So, the code statement "returnSize[1] = j;" is exactly out of bounds. So, in my opinion, "store to address 0x7fff6774f4f4 with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'" is just a euphemism for "out of bounds", which means you shouldn't access the memory space behind the pointed area.